# aws cli is not running from the gitlab ci runner

Tags: amazon-web-services, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

Below is the simple scipt that I am trying to execute with gitlab-ci.

```
image: 
  name: docker:latest

stages:
  - build
services:
  - docker:dind
  - registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cloud-deploy/aws-base:v0.3.6

Build:
  stage: build
  services:
  - registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cloud-deploy/aws-base:latest
  script:
    - aws s3 ls
```

I am getting the error

```
Using docker image sha256:114405a05c1ea1579eada94100ea1262ec351ce96625fed47684ed05ef48f52f for docker:latest with digest docker@sha256:0752ca4e936da012c173c119217c0f9599b3b191c1557e53206d5d06d2627580 ...
/bin/sh: eval: line 137: aws: not found
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: From the error, it seems like AWS CLI is not installed in your CI environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Looks like the Command from script stage is running on the Gitlab Runner itself not inside `aws-base` image.**

To Run Command `aws s3 ls` inside your container image `aws-base:v0.3.6` You should define Image Registry also inside your stage.

`image: registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cloud-deploy/aws-base:v0.3.6`

**After the image definition stage should be like this:**

```
Build:
  stage: build
  image: registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cloud-deploy/aws-base:v0.3.6
  services:
  - registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cloud-deploy/aws-base:latest
  script:
    - aws s3 ls
```

To use aws-base image make sure you had configured `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`, `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`, `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION` Variables inside your CI/CD Secrets/Variables

Comment: For authentication with AWS, I am using the oidc approach. I need to include the below script for fetching the auth token